# Probability of one quantity greater than another

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Suppose the lifetime of a species X is given by

$$f(x)$$

and the lifetime of a species Y is given by

$$g(y)$$

The joint density function is then

$$h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$$

Is the probability that species Y outlives species X given by

$$P(Y>X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}h(x,y)dydx$$?

Comment: You are correct provided that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.